# Why do I get "No data is available for the selected time frame"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Books API project, and the GCP shows "No data is available for the selected time frame" for the last 30 days. This message appears on both the "Metrics" and "Quotas" pages. See screenshots below.

Clearly there is data, which I can see via my app analytics reports.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
Following are some points that were missing on the original post:

- The Google Books API is used by an iOS app, which is available on the App Store and widely used across many iOS devices (iPhone and iPads) in many countries.
- There are thousands of iOS devices running my app so the Google Books API calls are invoked from thousands of endpoints with different locations and different IPs. All endpoints are using the same API_KEY.
- The Google Books API calls are performed successfully from the iOS devices and there is no API issue (I can clearly see that using analytics tool).
- The only issue I have, is with GCP console not showing the number of the API calls (and other metrics) associated with my API_KEY. As you can see in the previous screenshots, I get "No data is available for the selected time frame" anywhere.
- This is a regression issue since until recently I could successfully view the actual data of the API usage. I didn't change anything in this period.
- When going to GCP > IAM & Admin > Quotas, you can clearly see that the app indeed consumes API calls (see screenshot below).

Any suggestion why would the GCP console tell that no data is available, while data is indeed available?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation [1], Google Books respects copyright, contract, and other legal restrictions associated with the end user's location. As a result, some users might not be able to access book content from certain countries. For example, certain books are "previewable" only in the United States; we omit such preview links for users in other countries. Therefore, the API results are restricted based on your server or client application's IP address.

On the other hand, I hope link [2] could be helpful for you which seems similar to the issue you are facing. Also, documentation [3] [4] could be helpful for us to have more information about books API to use in the Google Cloud Platform.

[1] https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#UserLocation

[2] [Google books api always returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886400/google-books-api-always-returns-nothing)

[3] https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using

[4] https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started

Comment: Thank you for your response. I carefully read it and updated the original question accordingly, by adding a new section "UPDATE 1". I would highly appreciate your feedback.